Meaning of the "generators of a sigma-algebra"?
I am reading a textbook that contains the following claim:

Let $\Omega$ be a set and $\mathcal{P} = \{A_1, A_2,\dots\}$ a partition of $\Omega$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the given partition $\mathcal{P}$. Then the generators of $\mathcal{B}$ are of the form $A = \cup_{k\in J}A_k$ for subsets $J \subset N$, $A_k \in \mathcal{P}$

I am confused by the bolded part.  What does it mean the generators of $\mathcal{B}$ are of the given form? Aren't the generators of $\mathcal{B}=\sigma(\mathcal{P})$ simply the sets $\{A_1, A_2, \dots\}$? Also, we know that every event $E \in \mathcal{B}$ is itself a union a countable union of elements from $\mathcal{P}$ (e.g., Çınlar 2011, Exercise 1B), i.e., $\mathcal{B} = \{ \cup_{k \in J} A_k \mid J \subset N \} $, but this notion is different from the unions being the generators.

It would seem, since the $A_i$ are a partition, that what the question calls the generators is all of $\mathcal B,$ since it is closed under complements and countable unions and intersections.

They probably mean "the elements of B" instead of "the generators of B".

Maybe the bolded part refers to show you the "form" of this type of sets. You can prove that the family of sets of this form is the smallest sigma-algebra that contains the partition.
